# How to create offline Android apps development environment

Tags: android

I'm trying to create my android apps development environment. Now already installed the Android Studio(with SDK) and JDK. but when I'm trying to create my first apps, the Android studio is trying to get several dependencies from website.
I don't have internet connection on the development PC, is there any way to download the dependencies to local and setup an offline enviroment?

below are the error messages while I'm trying to build my first project.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugAndroidTestApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication2:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
>   Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy those dependencies to your .m2 directory and refer to that directory using below
`repositories {
   mavenLocal()
}`

and set gradle to offline mode.

Comment: There is m2repository located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository. but there are many sub folder inside. could you please help to specify the location of .m2 directory

Comment: Seems like the Maven is not installed, is it a necessary component of Android development environment?

Comment: It is normally where all the dependency gets downloaded